# MATLAB - How to rotate an orbit/sphere using rotation matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, rotation, orbit

I am trying to rotate an "orbit" using rotation matrix given below:

```
[cos(angle) -sin(angle) 0; 

 sin(angle) cos (angle) 0;

 0           0          1 ]
```

First thing I thought I should do was to use sphere():

```
[x y z] = sphere;
```

Then concatenate x, y, and z together in a vector:

```
xyz = [x; y; z];

rotatMat = [cos(angle) -sin(angle) 0; sin(angle) cos (angle) 0; 0  0  1 ];
```

multiply rotation matrix and xyz to rotate an orbit:

```
rotated = rotatMat .* xyz;
```

However, `xyz` turns out to be `62x22` dimension while my `rotatMat` is only `3x3` so I cannot multiply them together.

How can i fix this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`*`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) operator for matrix multiplication, and not [`.*`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) which is for element-wise multiplication.

Moreover, your `xyz` matrix should be of size `n-by-3` (and not `62-by-22`) and you have to use `xyz*rotatMat'` to match the dimensions correctly. Alternatively, you can have `xyz` of size `3-by-n` and use the syntax `rotatMat*xyz`.

Best,

Comment: I was typing my answer when I saw this (+1). I hope you don't mind that I've answered more or less the same (but with code)

Comment: @LuisMendo No pb for the answer. `xyz` should have 3 columns with the syntax `xyz*rotatMat'` and  3 rows with `rotatMat*xyz`. The output should be the same (but transposed).

Comment: Yes, I realized, that's why I deleted my comment. I'm more used to having the transformation matrix first and the coordinates last :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo That's funny, for me it is more natural to have the `xyz` coordinates columnwise, but that's just a matter of taste !

Comment: Well, I think it's more usual to have a column vector with `[x;y;z]`, where `x`, `y` `z` are numbers. See for example [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix). So if there are several points, each will be a column (`x`, `y`, `z` will be vectors). But of course it can be done the other way around

Answer (score 0):

```
xyz = [x(:) y(:) z(:)].'; %'// put x, y, z as rows of a matrix
xyz_rotated = rotatMat*xyz %// use matrix multiplication
x_rotated = reshape(xyz_rotated(1,:), size(x)); %// reshape transformed rows
y_rotated = reshape(xyz_rotated(2,:), size(x));
z_rotated = reshape(xyz_rotated(3,:), size(x));
```